# In Python, what happens if several variables point to the same list and the dynamic array is relocated in memory?

Tags: python, list

If I understand it correctly, in Python:

- Lists are implemented as dynamic arrays.
- If we assign a variable for a list to a new variable, then both variables point to the same list.

Please consider the following code in Python 3:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = list1
list1.extend(list(range(10000000)))
```

By using 10000000 I am hoping that this causes the underlying dynamic array for list1 to be relocated in memory. After the relocation, do `list1` and `list2` still point to the same location on memory? (I think they do because `print(len(list2))` gave me 10000003.) If so, how does Python do that? Does it keep track of how many variables are pointing to each object?

Comment: Yes, they are still the same list.  Keep in mind that the address of the list object is not the same as the address of the array used to hold the values.  The list object contains additional information, such as the list length.  So even though the address of the array may change, the address of the list object will not.

Comment: To add to that, the list object is really a header and one of the things in it is a pointer to an array of pointers to the list elements. When the pointer array is reallocated, the list object is updated, not replaced - the object id stays the same.

Comment: You should read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 0):

As you wrote
list2 = list1
you made a reference to the list1, didn't made a copy of its values. Unless you make a copy of the list1 python treats your assignment as reference to list1 in order to keep computer's memory nice and neat. If you want you can copy the first list as the example below:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = list1[:]
```

now you can work up with the lists separately.